# UK road network dataset

Tags: data, network, road, united-kingdom

Can anybody guide me to a website or a source to download the Geographical UK road network data set. The data set should include the road distances, since I want to apply shortest path search algorithm on it.

I searched the web for such data but I could not find it in readable format.

Comment: Are you a student/Academic, you could obtain the ITN from [edina](http://edina.ac.uk/)?

Comment: have a look at open street map.

Answer (score 4):

You can download the data from [open street map](http://www.openstreetmap.org/export#map=6/51.727/4.307) .Use the Export button on top left option to download data.
Additionally if you are looking for an routing/ networking algorithm you can have a look at [project OSRM](http://project-osrm.org/) which uses the above mentioned data for routing. hope it helps. good luck .

Answer (score 2):

When you say United Kingdom, you mean England, Wales, Scotland and Northern Ireland.

The data from the Ordnance Survey for Great Britain is for England, Wales and Scotland only, not Northern Ireland.

See [Ordnance Survey Products](https://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/opendatadownload/products.html) for free sources.

- Mid Scale 1:30,000-50,000 **Meridian2** vector data
- 1:10,000 (could be used a 1:5,000 as vector data)

For the most detailed, download all the tiles from **OS VectorMap™ District**.

Answer (score 2):

Very late reply but I posted a similar answer not long ago. You can download .csv file which contains roads of GB (not UK unfortunately but still might be useful) with the length measured in miles:

http://data.dft.gov.uk/gb-traffic-matrix/Traffic-major-roads-miles.csv

It also contains coordinate data for it to be immediately imported into various GIS softwares (tested this successfully with QGIS).

Answer (score 1):

If your a student, you can access the OS's ITN which will give you the best results. If not this dataset is very expensive and I'd use the OSM version.